# Correct reading of Set builder Notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

could anyone please let me know the correct reading(sentence form) of set builder notation, confused with different interpretation in different resources.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is "*The set of all $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds.*" Note that sometimes such collection is not a set (e.g. the collection of all sets); and sometimes we wish to limit the elements to be taken from a certain set $A$.

The set $\{x\in A\mid\varphi(x)\}$ is "*The set of all $x$ in $A$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is true.*"

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.

could you please clarify this "Note that sometimes such collection is not a set (e.g. the collection of all sets);" with some examples

Comment: @nish1013: There are several paradoxes of naive set theory which show that certain collections cannot be sets. For example the collection of all sets (as I remarked in my answer).