# Definitions of sets

Tags: notation

How would I define the set $\Omega_2(x)\ =\ \{4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39\dots\}$, where $\Omega_2$ is the set of semi primes (ie - numbers with $2$ not necessarily distinct prime factors)? I would like to define $\Omega_3$, etc. in a similar way.

I was thinking something along the lines of $\Omega_2(x)\ :=\{\mathbb{P}_p\cdot \mathbb{P}_q\ \rm{s.t}\ p=q\  \vee p \neq q \} $

## Update

$\Omega_2 \in \mathbb{N}\ \text{s.t.}\ \Omega_2:=\{\mathbb{P}_p\cdot \mathbb{P}_q\ \rm{s.t.}\ p=q\  \vee p \neq q \}\text{ where } p \wedge q \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: What is the significance of the $x$?

Comment: I assume $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes. What does the $_p$ do?

Comment: Good point! Would it be ok to omit it, or would I need to say that $\Omega_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ ...

Comment: $p \bigwedge q \in \mathbb{N}$ also

Comment: so $\mathbb{P}_p$ is the $p$th prime

Comment: You seem lost. $p$ is an integer, so what does $p \wedge q$ mean? You wanted $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, $\mathbb{THAT}$ font is usually used for special sets, so using it for numbers is odd. You can write $\Omega_2$ in therms of $n$th prime, $\{ p_i \cdot p_j \mid i, j \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\Omega_k = \underbrace {\mathbb{P}\cdot\mathbb{P}\cdots\mathbb{P}}_{\text{k times}}$$

Here $\mathbb{P}$ is a set of primes and $A \cdot B = \{a \cdot b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$.

Comment: I don't quite follow, but it looks impressive! would this suffice as a definition of all sets of k-almost primes then?

Comment: +1: I have altered the formatting slightly. Hopefully, it is to your liking.

Comment: I don't really understand where $A,B,a$ & $b$ come in. Not that I am questioning it, just that I am curious as to how they complete the definition.

Comment: What are $A$ & $B$ here?

Comment: @martin: $A$ and $B$ are intended to be arbitrary sets of numbers. Karolis is simply defining the notation $A\cdot B$ in this context.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the definition, "$\Omega_k$ is the set of all products of exactly $k$ not-necessarily-distinct primes"?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like [Gerry Myerson's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619838/), which is brief, clear, unambiguous, and to the point.  But if you really want a pile of notation, you might say:

$$\begin{align}\Omega_0 & = \{1\} \\
\Omega_{i+1} & = \{ n \mid \exists a\in\Omega_i: \exists p\in\Bbb P: n = ap\}
\end{align}$$

(I have marked this suggestion community wiki because I don't think it is a good idea.)

Comment: $\{ n \mid \exists a\in\Omega_i: \exists p\in\Bbb P: n = ap\}$ is a longer way to write $\{ap | a \in \Omega_i, p \in \Bbb P\}$.

Comment: I would have put it the other way around:  $\{ap\mid p\in\Omega_i, p\in \Bbb P\}$ is an abbreviation for the set that is normally written $\{ n \mid \exists a\in\Omega_i: \exists p\in\Bbb P: n = ap\}$. [See my discussion of this abbreviation here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/299195/).